# Change ViewController from the AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im trying to change `ViewController` from my `AppDelegate` when i receive a notification.

Here is what i've got so far:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{

    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive)
    {
        self.convViewController = self.window.rootViewController;

    }
    else if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive)
    {
        self.convViewController = self.window.rootViewController;

    }
}
```

I'm referencing my `ViewController` like this (in the .h file):

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) ConvViewController *convViewController;
```

However, when i click on a notification nothing happens.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to change the controller that is present on screen or just reference what is on-screen? Also, I don't see the difference between your two cases above: Active and Inactive are both getting a reference to the root controller.

Comment: What is supposed to happen? All you do is assign a property. That's it.

Comment: Im trying to change the view for the user to the `convViewController`

Comment: You need to reverse the statement to self.window.rootViewController = self.convViewController. But you also need different things in your if and else parts of the statement. Currently they're the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set:

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.convViewController;
```

You're assigning the wrong property. You need to be setting the *window's view controller* to change the view controller *presented by the window.*

In the above code you are setting you're convViewController to be a pointer to the window rootViewController.

Comment: Implemented this but now the screen goes all black, any ideas?

Comment: Check the validity of the convViewController's view. 
Is the convViewController initialised? Check if it's nil.

Comment: Like this? `UINavigationController *n1 = [[ConvViewController alloc]init];`

Comment: No. The code in my answer will work if self.convViewController had been initialised.
If it has not been initialised, initialise it with self.convViewController = [[ConvViewController alloc] init];

Comment: It partly worked, half of the screen is black now :)

Comment: This is a problem with ConvViewController. My answer is correct though. If you post a question about the ConvViewController I am sure that you can get help with it.

Answer (score 0):

Switch your logic:

self.window.rootViewController = self.convViewController;